# ReactJS set array data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to ask: Why userPost is empty?

```
function Feed() {
  const [userPost, setUserPost] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userID");
    const getUserPost = () => {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/profile/${userId}`)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data.posts);
          setUserPost(res.data.posts);
          console.log(userPost);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response);
        });
    };
    getUserPost();
  }, []);

  console.log(userPost);

  return (<></>)
}
```

Result: console.log(res.data.posts)

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: '6220c9c7c1750a6ec3618165', userId: {…}, …}
1: {_id: '6220d26dc1750a6ec36181a7', userId: {…}, …}
2: {_id: '6221de326c2cc78a2b758a63', userId: {…}, …}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Result: console.log(userPost)

```
[]
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `setUserPost` is an asynchronous operation. Therefore you cannot expect it to log right after the setter method.

```
setUserPost(res.data.posts);
console.log(userPost);
```

If you want to see the updated `userPost` value add the log to the method body of the `Feed` component. (Because `Feed` gets invoked when a state of the component updates)

```
function Feed() {
  const [userPost, setUserPost] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userID");
    const getUserPost = () => {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/profile/${userId}`)
        .then((res) => {
          setUserPost(res.data.posts);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response);
        });
    };
    getUserPost();
  }, []);

  console.log(userPost);

  return <></>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not empty! Setting state in React is not a sync function, it's async. You're logging the state before it is changed. If you log the userPost in the body of your component function, you will see the items are there.

```
function Feed() {
  const [userPost, setUserPost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userID");
    const getUserPost = () => {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/profile/${userId}`)
        .then((res) => {
          setUserPost(res.data.posts);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response);
        });
    };
    getUserPost();
  }, []);

  // LOG HERE
  console.log(userPost);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` is asynchronous, so that's why when you try to call `console.log(userPost);` instantly after `setUserPost(res.data.posts);`, `userPost` has not been updated yet.

If you want to understand more, you can read this article

https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia